# Мертвая зона из-за z-index

Tags: css, javascript

Есть шапка, которая является треугольным изображением в левом верхнем углу страницы. под нее уезжает контент страницы. Но div шапки создает мертвую зону своим z-index, и элементы под этой мертвой зоной становятся неактивными (не работают тултипы и нельзя кликнуть).
Как можно обойти эту мертвую зону?

Comment: @senderstream, очень сложно что-то определённое сазать, не видя кода. Добавьте код в ответ или залейте его на [http://jsfiddle.net/][1].

  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://sws.de-core.com.ua/category/projects

Внимание на ромбы пристыкованные к левому меню. они перекрыты z-index и попадают под мертвую зону

Comment: а поставить ромбам z-index выше нельзя?

Comment: Тогда они будут налазить на меню, а должны под него уезжать

Comment: Сам решил свой вопрос магическим свойством pointer-events